# "The user-provided container failed to start and listen on the port defined provided by the PORT=8080 environment variable. "

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, web-applications, dockerfile, google-cloud-run

Trying to deploy a Github Python application via Google Run. The app creates a docker image, but fails to deploy since I cannot find out how to setup a container to listen to this port.

I do not have a docker file - is that necessary to host a cloud-based app and define the port?
I am new to this.

Comment: Can you share more on what you do? Your code, dockerfile, your cloud run configuration.... Whatever that can give us more context

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.